# Output is NaN , how?

Tags: c++, nan, taylor-series

I am trying to code Taylor series but I am getting 'nan' as output in case of large value of n(=100).
Where am I doing things wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

 int main(){

    int n;
    double x;

    cin >> n;
    cin >> x;

    long double temp_val = 1;
    int sign = 1;
    int power = 1;
    long long int factorial = 1;


    for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++){

        sign = sign* -1 ;
        power =  2*i;
        factorial  = factorial*(2*i)*(2*i-1);

        temp_val += sign*pow(x,power)/factorial;
    }
    cout<<temp_val;

}
```

Comment: `power` looks like it could quickly overflow.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux any idea, how to resolve?

Comment: look at the actual values going into the function call that gave NaN.  It can help if you split the expression up into multiple separate lines so you can see the intermediate steps.

Comment: If `double` doesn't have the needed range, look at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Please don't fix the problem that you are asking about in the question. It makes the question and answers nonsensical for future readers. I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 5):

For large `n` your program has undefined behavior.

You are calculating the factorial of `2n` (so 200) in `factorial`. `200!` is, [according to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=200%21):

> 788657867364790503552363213932185062295135977687173263294742533244359449963403342920304284011984623904177212138919638830257642790242637105061926624952829931113462857270763317237396988943922445621451664240254033291864131227428294853277524242407573903240321257405579568660226031904170324062351700858796178922222789623703897374720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

For comparison, the typical largest value that a `long long int` can hold is

> 9223372036854775807

(which is assuming it is 64-bit)

Clearly you will not be able to fit `200!` into that. When you overflow a signed integer variable your program will have [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). That means that there will be no guarantee how it will behave.

But even if you change the variable type to be unsigned, not much will change. The program won't have *undefined behavior* anymore, but the `factorial` will not actually hold the correct value. Instead it will keep wrapping around back to zero.

Even if you change `factorial` to be type `double`, this will probably not be enough with at typical `double` implementation to hold this value. Your platform might have a `long double` type that is larger than `double` and able to hold this value.

You will have similar problems with `pow(x, power)` if `x` is not close to `1`.

As mentioned in the answer by @idclev463035818 the Taylor series, if evaluated straightforwardly, is numerically very ill-behaved and can not really be used practically in this form for large `n`.

Comment: nice, I was missing an explanation of what is wrong in OPs code from my answer, now they got both

Comment: thanks, it did work. `power` and `factorial` both were overflowing in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Calculating the taylor series has a trap that also occurs in other situations: Both the numerator and denominator of the terms to add grow rather fast and overflow easily, but their quotient converges to zero (otherwise adding them up till infinity would not converge to a finite number).

Instead of keeping track of both terms individually you need to update the result and the total increment. I wont provide you a full solution. In pseudo-code

```
double res = 0;
double delta = x;
int n = 1;
double sign = -1;
while ( ! stop_condition ) {
    delta *= (x / n);
    res += sign*delta;
    ++n;
    sign *= -1;
}
```